# Uniqueness of maximal compact group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, classical-groups

I'm studying the maximal compact subgroups of $PSL(2,\mathbb C)$.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup), "The Cartan-Iwasawa-Malcev theorem asserts that every connected Lie group (and indeed every connected locally compact group) admits maximal compact subgroups and that they are all conjugate to one another.  For a semisimple Lie group uniqueness is a consequence of the Cartan fixed point theorem, which asserts that if a compact group acts by isometries on a complete simply connected negatively curved Riemannian manifold then it has a fixed point."

Can I deduce that $P S U(2,\mathbb C)$ is the only maximal conpact subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb C)$? And how can I show the "uniqueness" by the Cartan fixed point theorem?

Comment: It's uniqueness up to conjugation.

Comment: I think uniqueness up to conjugation is independent of "semisimple". Then what is the uniqueness for semisimple Lie group means ?

Comment: Same thing.....

Comment: I agree the wording in WP is a bit unfortunate. In the case of semisimplicity, it is *not* that there is a stronger statement (it's still unique *up to conjugation*, as @MoisheKohan says), but that one can prove this with Cartan fixed point (whereas in the general case, presumably more machinery is needed). It should say, "For a semisimple Lie group, this uniqueness up to conjugation is a consequence ...". For such a proof via Cartan fixed point (in the only slightly more general case of reductive groups), compare https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/Cartan.pdf

Comment: You should explain what your problem really is: (1) Do you know how to prove that $PSU(2)$ is **a** maximal compact subgroup of $PSL(2,C)$? (2) In case you are already done with (1), are you asking how to prove that every maximal compact subgroup is conjugate to $PSU(2)$?  (3) Do you know which symmetric space corresponds to $PSL(2,C)$?

Comment: I misunderstood the meaning of WP. I thought in the semisimple case the statement can be stronger.